# JS not loading properly after hosting site

Tags: html, web-hosting, aws-cli, parallax.js

I have hosted my site on AWS server and I am encountering with weird problem When I load my page for the first time files are loaded as below

[image]

When I reload the site folder structure becomes
[image]

which is correct.

Hence my site is not behaving properly for the first time. Images are missing. Can somebody tell why this is happening?

Comment: What does "reload the site folder structure" mean?  Are you using some tool to see the folder structure?

Comment: When I refresh the browser, and press f12 I see the folder structure